# Use Javascript (not jQuery!) to perform word count on multiple form labels

Tags: javascript, forms, counter, label

I have multiple labels as part of my form and I'm unable to attach classes to them individually due to the constraints of the system I'm working within and they don't contain IDs. I need to style the labels differently depending on their content, e.g. if it has less than 5 words then I will style it one way, if it has more than 5 words I will style it another. I need to find a way to dynamically add a class to the label depending on whether it has less or more than 5 words.

Comment: Code and markup are worth 1024 words. :-) *(not my dv)* Suggest reading through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please give us a code example

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");


for(let ii = 0; ii < labels.length; ii++){
    let currentLabel = labels[ii];
    let words = currentLabel.innerHTML.split(' ');

  if(words.length >= 5)
  {
        currentLabel.className = "bold"
  }


}
```

[Here is a JsFiddle showing the example.](https://jsfiddle.net/f6d08oer/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/BzVkqm

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onLoad, false);

function onLoad() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('label'), assignClasses); 
}

function assignClasses(elem) {
  var words = elem.textContent.split(' ');

  elem.classList.add((words.length <= 5) ? 'fiveOrLess' : 'moreThanFive');
}
```